# Java GSON nested hashmap deserialization is flatmapped (duplicate key)

Tags: java, gson

I have a json like so

```json
{
  "NAME": {
    "keyClass": {
      "key1": 1,
      "key2": 2
    },
   "keyClass2": {
      "key1": 6
    }
  }
}
```

And my java look like that

```java
@Expose
    protected Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

where each `Map<String,Integer>` is a `new LinkedHashMap<>()`, I then seralize that with `GSON.toJson(this,File)` and it give me that wonderful json, the issue arise when I try to deserialize it as `GSON.fromJson(File,this)` will try to map everything except that somehow it has a flatmap and doesnt care about nesting thus think keyClass.key1 and keyClass2.key1 clash. It throw a magnificient duplicate key: null . Is there some kind of object so the nested LinkedHashMap get serialized as its own and is not flatmap when deserialized?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think `duplicate key: null` means that `key1` is duplicated? To me it says that the key `null` is duplicated. Somehow the `null` key is making it into the map, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually forgot to tell something, I am using an Enum which map to a string that's why, here the two examples and why it fails on the first one: https://gist.github.com/hube12/b86e8257e89ed4220f03f9a527175fca